# Regex to match CDATA section

Tags: xml, regex

I need a regex to match:

starts with

```
<![CDATA[
```

contains:

`wildcard`

(alot of them, including but not limited to`<>"./` and letters and numbers across multiple lines).

and ends in:

```
]]>
```

Im using it to clear out a VERY large ajax xml file's lipsum.

Ive looked around and cannot figure out how to match an exclamation point

I tried generating one with http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php, which gave:

```
/^(?:<\!\[CDATA\[)\]\]>$/m
```

which does not match in the testers or editor im using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this regex

```
<!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]>
```

OR

```
 <!\[CDATA\[((?:[^]]|\](?!\]>))*)\]\]>
```

[Please See Demo Here](http://rubular.com/r/z9T2gZNnE6)

Comment: both hit. The first one is so easy. I guess you don't escape the ! at all, just the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below PERL code which matches to regex which is desired.

PERL Code :-

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin
$regex = "<![CDATA[ Shanghai Taipei Tokyo !!!!?<,;'[*()&^%$#@! CDATA TorontoOxford ] is a registered [trade mark of Oxford University Pressin the UK New YorkRevised text ?? John Guy 2000 ]]>";
if ("$regex" =~ m/^(<!\[CDATA\[)/ && "$regex" =~ m/(\]\]>)$/)
{
    print "Success scenario matched \n";
    print "$regex is matched \n";
} else {
    print "Failure scenario matched \n";
    print "$regex is not matched \n";
}
```

Output :-

```
Success scenario matched
<![CDATA[ Shanghai Taipei Tokyo !!!!?<,;'[*()&^%-1! CDATA TorontoOxford ] is a r
egistered [trade mark of Oxford University Pressin the UK New YorkRevised text ?
? John Guy 2000 ]]> is matched
```

Hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I couldn't use that regex and I dont use perl. Maybe it will help someone else who finds this on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Thatoneguy7 The Idea is in the regex the parentheses () helps to match the exact regrex mentioned in it. So try to look same options in the lang. you are using. May be it might be there with some different options not with ().